# Transforming Image into Binary String

Tags: java, loops, bufferedimage

I am trying to concatenating every pixel of a image together to form a binary String.
However, the following code will not produce anything.
If I put the System.out.println at the // position, It will print out something but I am sure that is not correct.

I think it's something about looping....

What is the problem here?
How can I modify my code?

```
public static void main(String[] argv){

    BufferedImage img1 = null;

    try {
        img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/Sam/Desktop/Image2/00001.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    int width1 = img1.getWidth();
    int height1 = img1.getHeight();

    String con = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < height1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width1; j++) {
            int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(j, i);

            con += Integer.toBinaryString(rgb1);          

        }
         //System.out.println(con);

    }
     System.out.println(con);

}
```

Comment: Printing out binary data to a console is likely not going to display properly. Pipe the output to a file (`java myprogram > raw_image_data`) then inspect the file with a hex editor.

Comment: Please format/indent your code properly. Also don't leave empty catch statements, at least add `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: thanks I have changed the code format

Comment: "It will print out something but I am sure that is not correct."  What will it print out and why do you think it's incorrect?  Incidentally, building strings using repeated calls to `+=` in Java is _really_ inefficient.  Consider using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: Don't concatenate strings with `+` in a loop. It's going to create a ton of temporary string objects. Use a `StringBuilder` instead. Also, this is going to be a very long string of zeros and ones without a newline, so you might not see all of it on the IDE console. Why are you doing this and what's the expected output?

Comment: Are you sure your height1 and width1 are correct. Maybe check their values. Also, do you have a debugger? You can step through your program and see where the mistake is made.

Comment: I don't know how big your image is, but you're generating 16 characters per pixel.  For a 900 x 1200 portrait image, that's 17,280,000 characters.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc where do you get 16 characters per pixel? It could be up to 24 and as few as 1.

Comment: @matt: You're right and that's the problem with the OP's code.  He's not zero padding the output of the Integer.toBinaryString(rgb1); call to 32 (not 16) characters.  Our mistake.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have just decoded a video into image per frame. I want to use this way to represent the whole video as a long string. More steps will be done later. I am now trying to decode a single image into binary string at this stage.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc What is zero padding? Can you explain more to me? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you look into some other solution then. Using Base64 is much better, as it is standard, more compact, and allows having newlines in the text so that it's readable. As @GilbertLeBlanc said, each pixel is going to take up 32 characters, which for a whole video is going to be ginormous. Besides, that doesn't include the video metadata such as key frames and timing.

Comment: For example, an HD frame 1920x1080 has 2,073,600 pixels. Multiply that by 32, and you get 66,355,200 characters for a single frame. Now, a 5 minute video clip at 30 fps - multiply the above by 30x60x5, and you get a text file sized 597,196,800,000 bytes. That half a Terabyte. With base64 it's going to be around a sixth of that, but still - I wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a class we use to serialise an image file to a string, so we can embed the image in a html file.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BinaryCodec;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ImageUtil {

    public static String getEmbeddedImage(String resourcePath)  {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = ImageUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
            if (is != null) {
                byte buffer[] = new byte[is.available()];
                String fileExtension = getImageTypeFromFileName(resourcePath);
                String encodedImage = BinaryCodec.toAsciiString(buffer);
                encodedImage = "data:image/".concat(fileExtension).concat(encodedImage);
                return encodedImage;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if(is != null) {
                try { is.close(); } catch(IOException e) {}
            }
        }
        return  null;
    }

    public static String getImageTypeFromFileName(String imagePath) {
        String parts[] = imagePath.split("\\.");
        return parts[parts.length-1].toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that help the OP or answer the question? He wants *binary* representation, not base64. You are not telling him what's wrong with his code, nor are you giving him a solution to the problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sorry - i pressed submit too quickly there, i've updated the example to use the BinaryCodec now.

Comment: Yeah, but have you compiled and tried it? Because this won't compile. How about writing an answer to the question that actually pays attention to the question? The OP is not using a resource but rather an absolute path. There is no need to convert the output to URL. Don't just throw code at a question.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageIO` does not guarantee your image will be loaded when it returns.

You should use an `ImageObserver` or `MediaTracker` to check that the file has loaded.
You may need to wait!

Have you checked whether the `width1` and `height1` are sensible values, when your loop executes?

Comment: Yes I have tried to print out i and j, they are the right value;(

Comment: OK. It might not be the problem. But have you checked the pixels are actually loaded? thats what `mediatracker` allows you to do.

Comment: Also, pay attention to @gilbert-le-blanc point: if you don't zero pad your values to a fixed bit width, you are likely to get uninterpretable values out!!